# SendAsync always showing Status Waiting using MVCmailer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcmailer

I am developing application in MVC5 and MVCMailer. I am sending email using SendAsync command which always show Status = "WaitingforResponse" and mail is not sent. If I use "Send" command instead, it works fine. Here is my code:

```
var v = new UserMailer().SendCampaignMail("email_address").SendAsync();
```

and UserMailer.cs

```
 public virtual MvcMailMessage SendCampaignMail(string Email)
    {
        try
        {
            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.Subject = "Campaing";
                x.ViewName = "PasswordReset";
                x.To.Add(Email);
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Screenshot for response: http://prntscr.com/82yfwq
Thanks for your Help:

Comment: What happens if you get the return property of the returned `Task` (ie. `var result = v.result`): this will force a wait for the task to complete.

Comment: Thank for response but sorry, I could not getting you. Should I change somewhere?

Comment: Yes: what happens if you wait for the task complete? (Getting the value of the tasks `Result` property will do this).

Comment: var result = v.IsCompleted; if I use this, it returns me false. there isn't any result property for MVCMailer

Comment: `v.Result`! (look at my first comment)

Comment: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: OK, so its `Task` (and not `Task<T>`), so in that case try its `Wait` method. (you need to have something that waits – maybe not blocking – for the send to either complete or fail and in the latter case tell you why. I suspect your `MvcMailMessage` meybe being GC'ed before it completes sending).

Comment: bool result = v.Wait(-1); I tried this, but it goes to infinite wait

Comment: So the synchronous version works but the async version never completes. Sounds like a bug in the type. Eg. could it be like [this](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/93)?